# How to prevent JupyterLab from overwriting my settings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

My JupyterLab version is 3.5.0. I want the shortcuts to be similar with vscode, and customize them at the following path (on Mac)

```
~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension/shortcuts.jupyterlab-settings
```

but each time reopen JupyterLab, this file `shortcuts.jupyterlab-settings` will be overwritten, and the disabled shortcuts will be added back automatically.

For example, the disabled key

```
            "command": "notebook:change-cell-to-markdown",
            "keys": [
                "M"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
            "disabled": true
        },
```

will be replaced by

```
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "notebook:change-cell-to-markdown",
            "keys": [
                "M"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        },
```

The following screenshot shows the differences: the LHS is my settings, and the RHS is the file `shortcuts.jupyterlab-settings` overwritten by JupyterLab.

[image]

How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Does it happen if you edit from inside JupyterLab? To do that open JupyterLab and use 'Settings' > 'Advanced Settings Editor' and then choose anything from the list so the 'JSON Settings Editor' option toggle comes up in the upper left. Toggle that and then choose 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and edit the 'User Preferences' on the  right side.

Comment: @Wayne It still happens. Actually I tried this first.

Comment: @Wayne I have another two questions. 1) I don't find the keyname corresponding to the function key of mac keyboard. Is there a way of using function key in JupyterLab?  2) Is it possible to detect whether the curser is at the beginning of line or not by some `"selector"`? I want to switch from the edit mode to cell mode by `ArrowLeft` if the curser is at the beginning of a line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: lock the file `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension/shortcuts.jupyterlab-settings` to disable this silly behaviour.

Comment: Besides, there is also a peculier bug, `Ctrl Enter` cannot by used as a shortcut.